# Recreate file path from a json directory sturcture in python

Tags: python, directory

I have a json which maps out a directory structure.

```
{
 "/": {
  "home": {
   "usr": {
    "Documents": {
     "Scripts": {
      "hse": {
       "2023-04-13 12:54:55.169974.log": {"hash": "123zyx"},
       "hse3.py": null,
       "hse2.py": null,
       "hse.py": null,
       "Resources": {
        "Ideas.odt": null,
        "15 research-based questions.odt": null,
        "Archive": {
         "Solutions.odt": null 
}}}}}}}}}
```

Sometimes files have a dictionary sometimes they have a null value.

How do I recreate the full file path for each file? I won't know in advance how deep the structure will become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this...

### ...Edited Version!!

```py
import os
import json

with open("test.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

def getFullPath(data):
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        return None
    paths = []
    for root, dat in data.items():
##      Used this to stop hash 
##      if root == "hash":
##          continue
        sub_paths = getFullPath(dat)
        if sub_paths is None:
            paths.append(root)
            continue
        for sub_path in sub_paths:
            if sub_path is not None:
                path = os.path.join(root, sub_path)
                paths.append(path)
    return paths

print(*getFullPath(data), sep="\n")

path = ['/', 'home', 'usr', 'Documents', 'Scripts', 'hse', '2023-04-13 12:54:55.169974.log']

dat = data
for sub_path in path:
    dat = dat[sub_path]
print(json.dumps(dat, indent=2))

# -----------------------------------------------------

paths = getFullPath(data) # First get the full list
paths_iter = iter(paths) # Use iter to turn it into a generator

print(next(paths_iter)) # Now you can get paths one at a time
print(next(paths_iter)) # Next
print(next(paths_iter)) # Next
```

Comment: Thanks John. What if I need to access the value of a key? Say I use Path().parts to break   down the path ['/', 'home', 'usr', 'Documents', 'Scripts', 'hse', '2023-04-13 12:54:55.169974.log']  How would I access this key in the original json?

Comment: Also what is your suggestion of avoiding the situation where I have a folder called "hash" which your code will skip over?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know that hash was a folder.

Comment: Thanks again John. I wonder if it's possible to go one step further and turn this into a generator so getFullPath() yields one result at a time?